# Using UIAppearance for separate UI elements

Tags: ios, uikit, uiappearance

I'd like to use `UIAppearance` to set the size of the font of all the `UIButtons` in my app to 15, and the size of the font in all the `UILabels` in my app to 10. Here's what I have:

```
UIFont *dinMediumFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DINPro-Medium" size:15];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIButton class], nil] setFont:dinMediumFont];

UIFont *dinBoldFontBig = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DINPro-Bold" size:10];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:nil] setFont:dinBoldFontBig];
```

However, I'd like the font of the buttons in `UINavigationBars` to be smaller, I tried adding this:

```
UIFont *smallerFont =[UIFont fontWithName:@"DINPro-Medium" size:15];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIButton class], [UINavigationBar class], nil] setFont:smallerFont];
```

but the font is staying as the default... Why could that be?

Comment: What's your question? So far you have made a statement and posted some code.

Comment: sorry, just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in navigation bars aren't instances of `UIButton` nor any of its subclasses; instead they're instances of `UIBarButtonItem`.

`UIBarButtonItem`'s text isn't actually a `UILabel` instance: instead of setting properties on `UILabel`'s appearance-in-`UIButton` proxy, your second snippet will need to set the `font` property on `UIBarButtonItem`'s appearance proxy.